# Merge info from one dataframe to another based on matching column

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe (`con`) that looks like:

```
tag                         Consequence
HSB670|ENSG00000147996      upstream_gene_variant
HSB666|ENSG00000147996      upstream_gene_variant
HSB651|ENSG00000174749      downstream_gene_variant
HSB195|ENSG00000188157      splice_variant
```

And a second dataframe (`period`) that looks like:

```
Sample      expr        Gene                Period  tag
"HSB651"    3.207474    "ENSG00000174749"   4       HSB651|ENSG00000174749
"HSB670"    3.797228    "ENSG00000147996"   4       HSB670|ENSG00000147996
"HSB195"    0.214731    "ENSG00000188157"   4       HSB195|ENSG00000188157 
"HSB666"    3.663308    "ENSG00000147996"   5       HSB666|ENSG00000147996
```

I want to merge in the Consequence info from `con` to `period`. They have the `tag` columns in common, so basically, wherever the tags are similar, I want pandas to find the corresponding `Consequence` and add it to the `period` dataframe. It should look like this in the end:

```
Sample      expr        Gene                Period  tag                     Consequence 
"HSB651"    3.207474    "ENSG00000174749"   4       HSB651|ENSG00000174749  downstream_gene_variant
"HSB670"    3.797228    "ENSG00000147996"   4       HSB670|ENSG00000147996  upstream_gene_variant
"HSB195"    0.214731    "ENSG00000188157"   4       HSB195|ENSG00000188157  splice_variant
"HSB666"    3.663308    "ENSG00000147996"   5       HSB666|ENSG00000147996  upstream_gene_variant
```

I've tried this but it's giving me strange results:

`merge = pd.merge(period, con, on="tag", how="left")`

Results:

```
   SampleID      expr             Gene  Period                     tag      Consequence  
0    HSB670  3.797228  ENSG00000147996       4  HSB670|ENSG00000147996      NaN  
1    HSB666  3.663308  ENSG00000147996       5  HSB666|ENSG00000147996      upstream_gene_variant   
2    HSB666  3.663308  ENSG00000147996       5  HSB666|ENSG00000147996      upstream_gene_variant   
3    HSB666  3.663308  ENSG00000147996       5  HSB666|ENSG00000147996      upstream_gene_variant   
4    HSB666  3.663308  ENSG00000147996       5  HSB666|ENSG00000147996      upstream_gene_variant   
5    HSB651  3.207474  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB651|ENSG00000174749      downstream_gene_variant       
6    HSB651  3.207474  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB651|ENSG00000174749      downstream_gene_variant   
7    HSB651  3.207474  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB651|ENSG00000174749      downstream_gene_variant   
8    HSB651  3.207474  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB651|ENSG00000174749      downstream_gene_variant   
9    HSB651  3.207474  ENSG00000174749       4  HSB651|ENSG00000174749      downstream_gene_variant   
10   HSB195  0.214731  ENSG00000188157       4  HSB195|ENSG00000188157      splice_variant   
11   HSB195  0.214731  ENSG00000188157       4  HSB195|ENSG00000188157      splice_variant   
12   HSB195  0.214731  ENSG00000188157       4  HSB195|ENSG00000188157      splice_variant
```

Comment: Use  `merge = df1.merge(df2, on="tag", how="inner")`.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with your code. I tried it and produced the result you want. Can you edit your question with your "strange results"?

Comment: @IgorRaush: See update! I get a bunch of duplicate rows...

Comment: it looks like you're experiencing a fanout, likely due to duplicate `tag` values in the `con` dataframe.